# index method not returning the view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a crud application using resource route, But my index method not returning any view
while using route http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/index

route file
`Route::resource("admin","StudentController");`

controller
 `public function index(){return view("welcome");}`

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel routing system has changed slightly in Laravel 8.x, and now requires the fully qualified class name of the controller:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentController');
```

Comment: i'm totally beginner with this technology. i'm trying to make a simple example from a tutoriel.so i wanted to know what the problem with my code

Comment: laravel route system has changed ...previous versions works as such Route::resource("admin","StudentController");

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource("admin","App\Http\Controllers\StudentController");
public function index(){return view("welcome");}
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the `index` route. The URI you are using  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/index is for the `show` route not `index`. The `index` route would be  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ .

Most likely you have nothing being returned from your `show` method of your Controller so its a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

> just try this
> When you use resources method then index and create funtion use same url but method different like index use get and create use post
> Then try this http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin